# Can WIMPS be stable for a long time given that they are 60 times heavier than a proton and other particles heavier than protons decay rapidly?

Tags: dark-matter

WIMPS are dark matter candidates  But how can they be stable for billions of years ?

Comment: Depends on what they actually are, their physics, and their possible decay paths.

Comment: Just because they could decay doesn't mean they do it quickly.

Comment: @ProfRob - indeed, Bismuth-209, decidedly more than 60 times heavier than a proton, has a half-life (alpha decay) estimated at 4.6E19 years, significantly more than a paltry billion years.